# Dividing main function into other functions in opencv using c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am learning opencv using c++. As I don't have any background knowledge in c++.I am learning it parallel with opencv. Here is my doubt.My main program is very big.So,I want to divide it into small functions and call them whenever necessary in a loop using conditional statements.I have searched over the net and observed that people are writing codes in a similar way(dividing it into smaller functions).I found this very convenient as it makes my program understandable.Is there any other reasons for why I should use more function calls? Does it effect my processing speed in any way? Which one of above two methods takes more memory space?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always do things that improve the readability and understandability of your code when first learning a language. (And, in many cases, well beyond that point.) Readability of code should be your number one priority at this point.

That being said, functions do not really cost any more time than clumping all your code together. (Especially as smart compilers will inline your functions anyways.) And the memory use is practically the same as well.

So in short, yes, if functions (or pretty much anything else) improves your code's readability and convenience, use it.